# Node JS printing complete JSON object as a key

Tags: node.js, express

I have written following code to read JSON Object from request. The issue is that it prints the whole object in 1 key and set empty value of it.

This is what i am doing.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies



/**
 * 
 * Add User 
 */

app.post('/addUser', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  })
```

I am passing following object to this route.

> {"id": 1, "name": "Taha" }

and getting this as output.

> { '{"id": 1,\n"name": "Taha"\n}': '' }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue on the client. Send the request with Content-Type: application/json in the header.

Comment: Thanks, Yes it was client issue, i didn't know about `Content-Type`